# Wordpress Theme - Disabling Drop Down Menu on Sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I'm a newbie here so your helps are appreciated.

I'm building a new forum site using ForumEngine Wordpress Theme, so far so good. But there is a problem I can't solve.

You can see my site: http://forum.banaisbul.com/ and as you can see there is a navigation bar on the right of the screen that shows the main forum categories and when you click the arrow, it drops down to show the sub-categories.

But I want to show that sub-categories by default, so I want users not to click the arrow to see the rest of the sub-categories.

Is it possible? What should I do to do this?

Comment: nothing because I have no knowledge about coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this codes for what you are want to happen.

```
<h2>Kategoriler</h2>
<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/is-yasami/ ">Is Yasami</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/mulakatlar/ ">Kariyer Sohbeti</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/calisma-hayati/ ">Çalisma Hayati   </a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/yoneticilik/ ">Yöneticilik</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/yeni-mezunlar/ ">Yeni Mezunlar</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/ogrenciler-stajyerler/ ">Ögrenciler - Stajyerler</a></li>
```

```
<h2>Kariyer</h2>
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/ozgecmis/ ">Özgeçmis</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/is-yasami/ ">Mülakatlar</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/meslekler/ ">Ön Yazi</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/sirketler/ ">Sirketler</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/sektorler/ ">Sektörler</a></li>
```

```
<h2>Gelisim</h2>
<ul style="list-style-type:square">
    <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kisisel-gelisim/">Kisisel Gelisim</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kitaplar/">Kitaplar</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/videolar/">Videolar</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/basari-hikayeleri/">Basari Hikayeleri</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In Which file should I copy this code?

Answer (score 0):

Find the code below and replace the code from above that i posted.

```
<div class="widget widget-categories">
            <h2>Kategoriler</h2>
            <ul class="category-items">
                    <li id="nav_cat_2" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/is-yasami/ ">
                İş Yaşamı                   <span class="flags color-36"></span>
            </a>
                                <a class="arrow  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav_cat_children_2">
                    <span></span>
                </a> 
                                                <ul id="nav_cat_children_2" class="child collapse ">
                                <li id="nav_cat_3" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kariyer-sohbeti/ ">
                Kariyer Sohbeti                 <span class="flags color-38"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_4" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/calisma-hayati/ ">
                Çalışma Hayatı                  <span class="flags color-32"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_5" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/yoneticilik/ ">
                Yöneticilik                 <span class="flags color-33"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_6" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/yeni-mezunlar/ ">
                Yeni Mezunlar                   <span class="flags color-6"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_7" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/ogrenciler-stajyerler/ ">
                Öğrenciler - Stajyerler                 <span class="flags color-39"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>       
                </ul>
                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_8" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kariyer/ ">
                Kariyer                 <span class="flags color-36"></span>
            </a>
                                <a class="arrow  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav_cat_children_8">
                    <span></span>
                </a> 
                                                <ul id="nav_cat_children_8" class="child collapse ">
                                <li id="nav_cat_9" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/ozgecmis/ ">
                Özgeçmiş                    <span class="flags color-38"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_10" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/mulakatlar/ ">
                Mülakatlar                  <span class="flags color-32"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_11" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/on-yazi/ ">
                Ön Yazı                 <span class="flags color-33"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_12" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/meslekler/ ">
                Meslekler                   <span class="flags color-6"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_13" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/sirketler/ ">
                Şirketler                   <span class="flags color-37"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_14" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/sektorler/ ">
                Sektörler                   <span class="flags color-39"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>       
                </ul>
                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_15" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/gelisim/ ">
                Gelişim                 <span class="flags color-36"></span>
            </a>
                                <a class="arrow  collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#nav_cat_children_15">
                    <span></span>
                </a> 
                                                <ul id="nav_cat_children_15" class="child collapse ">
                                <li id="nav_cat_16" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kisisel-gelisim/ ">
                Kişisel Gelişim                 <span class="flags color-38"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_17" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/kitaplar/ ">
                Kitaplar                    <span class="flags color-32"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_18" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/videolar/ ">
                Videolar                    <span class="flags color-33"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>           <li id="nav_cat_19" class="">
            <a class="cat-item " href="http://forum.banaisbul.com/Kategori/basari-hikayeleri/ ">
                Başarı Hikayeleri                   <span class="flags color-35"></span>
            </a>
                                        </li>       
                </ul>
                        </li>       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did I supply the correct code what you want to happen?

Comment: exactly, that worked so good, thank you again, I'm appreciated.